# Apply a function to each group in r to create multiple dataframes and combine them all in r

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a complex function that returns a dataframe by using id column from a dataframe and I want to apply that function for each unique id. At the end I will have a dataframe for each unique id and at the end i want to combine them all into one table. Something like this.

```
data <- data.frame(c = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                num = (seq(1,6))) # this is the dataframe 

test <- function(group, city){
  df = data[data$c == group, ]
  df$d <- city
  return(data.frame(df))
} # function 

# applying to each group 
df <- test("A", "Chicago") 
df1 <- test("B", "New York")
df2 <- test("C", "Los Angeles")

# combine all the dataframe
final <- rbind(df, df1, df2)
```

how can I accomplish this in R without manually applying a function to each group? Hopefully using dplyr and purr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `map` (`map2` as you have 2 arguments) to produce a list of dataframes and then `bind_rows` to combine the elements in the list to a single dataset (documentation [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html)).

Something like this:

```r
arg1 = c("A","B","C")
arg2 = c("Chicago", "New York", "Los Angeles")

list_of_dataframes = map2(arg1, arg2, test)
single_dataframe = bind_rows(list_of_dataframes)
```

**Edit:** Given your comment, perhaps what you want is a for loop? This is probably easier to think about but misses out on some of R's elegance.

```r
# create empty dataframe
output_df = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(arg1)){
  # make dataframe for i-th combination of inputs
  this_df = test(arg1[i], arg2[i])
  # append i-th df to output
  output_df = bind_rows(output_df, this_df)
}
```

Note that there is no requirement to iterate through `arg1` and `arg2`. Your inputs to the function can be arbitrary.

Comment: hi this was just an example! I actually have a way more complex function that returns a dataframe by using id column from another dataframe and i want to use that function for each unique id. i want to know how i can repeat a function that returns a dataframe.

Comment: This approach does not depend on the complexity of your function. So long at `test` returns a function `map` or `map2` will return you a list of dataframes (the function applied to each input choice). You can then combine a list of dataframes into a single dataframe using `bind_rows`.